# How to Pragmatically scroll in el-table as the current selected row changes? Element.io

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am trying to update de viewport of el-table in Element.io as I set the current row (setCurrentRow) using the down button. I have tried:

```
this.$refs.SearchTable.syncPostion();
this.$refs.SearchTable.updateScrollY();
```

My current call function is :

```
selectUpFromSearchTable(){
                if(this.SearchResult.length > 0 && this.rowIndex-1 >= 0){
                    this.rowIndex--;
                }
                else{
                    this.rowIndex;
                }
               // Update selected element in table. 
                this.$refs.SearchTable.setCurrentRow(this.SearchResult[this.rowIndex]);
                // function to update table scroll position here this.$refs.SearchTable.updateScrollY(this.rowIndex);
            }
```

My goal is for the table to update its scroll position as I change the selected row. Any ideas how I could do this using a native Element UI / Vue function?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was more of a HTML DOM manipulation. 
The code to select the current row and ask it to come into view was:

```
            var ScrollTable = document.querySelector('.SearchTable');
            var innerTable = ScrollTable.querySelector('.el-table__body');
            var innerTbody = innerTable.querySelector('tbody');
            var currentRow = innerTbody.querySelector('.current-row');
            currentRow.scrollIntoView();
```